# How to write to a file using awk to find a string in between ( ); and add a printline after ; to print the string found?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, pattern-matching

I have some files in a folder that has several sqrt(x+y); functions. I want to find out what is in x+y. So I want to read the value inside sqrt(x+y  ); and add a printf(x+y ); after the semicolon. I was trying this for about a month. But still cannot find a way.

Please help. If you know where I can find any good tutorial or book about AWK please let me know.. Thanks.
Following is the algorithm that I figured. (I am totally new to AWK)

loop thro all files{
if one line starts with sqrt( start put the strings in to  variable a /or array a
            until find );
        write Print ( , concatenate, then the value , concatenate,); 
        in the next line.

Comment: Why don't you post some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

files=(*.txt)

for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i++)) ; do
    file="${files[$i]}"
    awk -f f.awk "$file" > "${file}.mod"
done
```

where `f.awk` is:

```
{
    gsub(/\([^)]*\)/,"&; printf&")
    print
}
```

Note that this will not work for nested parenthesis, like `sqrt(4+2*(x+y))`.. (If that is needed I can try to update my answer.).

Given example file `input.txt`:

```
x=7;
sqrt(x+5*4); sqrt(x*x); 
i=3;
a=2+sqrt(8);
```

Running: `awk -f f.awk input.txt` gives:

```
x=7;
sqrt(x+5*4); printf(x+5*4); sqrt(x*x); printf(x*x); 
i=3;
a=2+sqrt(8); printf(8);
```

For Gnu Awk, I recommend the following Awk resource: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Comment: Its very clear and thanks for the link. I need to run this to add print() to all the files with sqrt in the directory. It has some paranthesis inside. I gave the command awk -f f.awk input.txt>>output.txt to write it to a different file; but I want this in the same filenot in output.txt. That was what took me long time to do this

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks. If you want it in the same file you can first move `input.txt` to e.g. `input.txt.bak` and then do `awk -f f.awk input.txt.bak > input.txt`.. Do you need support for nested parenthesis like `sqrt(4+2(x+y))`?

Comment: Thanks I used a shell script to run the f.awk script you gave and it worked correctly. If I want to output sqrt(x); print *, "x" instead of sqrt(x);printf(x); how should I change this awk script? I changed the f.awk like following:        gsub(/sqrt(\[^)]*\"/,"&; print*,\"&")    But this will still print the paranthesis. How do you replace the paranthesis with " " here. The meaning of [^)]*\" section is not clear to me still.

Comment: @MadHatter Hi! Try to replace `f.awk` with `{ print gensub(/\(([^)]*)\)/,"&, print \"\\1\"","g")}`..

Comment: @MadHatter The meaning of `\([^)]*\)`: 1) Match opening left parenthesis: `\(`. 2. Match any character that is not closing right parenthesis: `[^)]`. 3. Repeat number 2. as many times as possible: `*`. 4. Match closing right parenthesis: `\)`.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is certainly a fine tool, but why not stretch a little?  If you are willing to discard the whitespace inside the parentheses, try:

```
cat << 'EOF' - input-file | m4
divert(-1)
define(`sqrt',`divert(1)'$1
`divert(-1)')
EOF
```

That should print out every string that appears within a call to `sqrt` in the file named `input-file`.  This will not evaluate the strings, but it's not clear to me if you want that.

The primary advantage of this solution is that it will work well with nested parentheses.  That is, lines of the form `sqrt( foo( bar( x + y )))` will correctly print `foo( bar( x + y ))`, and that will be difficult to parse correctly with `awk`.  The primary disadvantage is that it requires correct syntax on the input (unbalanced parentheses will cause problems).