# How to grep the word next to the search word (....) using Shell script?

Tags: shell, awk

I wrote a shell script to identify given word and  grep the word next to the given word. Please see my sample input file below.  Also I need to write the  same file as shown below in my sample output file.

```
#!/bin/bash 

LOGFILE=$1 

if [ -f $LOGFILE ]
then 
        sed -i.bak 's/sqrt(\(\w*\))/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g' $LOGFILE
else 
        echo "$LOGFILE not found " 
fi
```

but when I run this shell script nothing happens in my file. Could you please help me?

Example input  file:

```
wewe **sqrt(a+B)**  eeenwerer ergv. **sqrt(2x-3)** gtgnwerer ergv. **sqrt(wea*B)** gjjj nwerer ergv. **sqrt(a2/B)** rrnwerer ergv.
```

Expected file output:

```
wewe **sqrt(a+B)** eeenwerer ergv. ***write (a+B);*** **sqrt(2x-3)** gtgnwerer ergv. ***write (2x-3);*** ** **sqrt(wea*B)** gjjj nwerer ergv. ***write (wea*B);*** ** **sqrt(a2/B)** rrnwerer ergv.***write (a2/B);*** **
```

Comment: Are you sure that the input wouldn't contain `sqrt(a+(b*c)/d)` or something, i.e. nested parenthesis?

Comment: well this is my sample  :                                              in put collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 4D0*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt(lambda)**) collisionf2.F90:  temp_cons = 15*sml_pi/(lambda***sqrt

Comment: Please update the question with your sample input.

Comment: i update the question with more sample input

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365990/how-to-write-to-a-file-using-awk-to-find-a-string-in-between-and-add-a-prin

Comment: Add an explanation for WHY that is the expected output given your input. Include the "word" you are searching for. Also, define what a "word" means to you (contiguous alphabetic chars? alphanumerics? anything between spaces? something else?).

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
awk -f mod.awk input.txt
```

where `input.txt` is you input log file, and `mod.awk` is:

```
{
    str=str $0 ORS
}
END {
    str2=""
    prev=""
    while(match(str,/sqrt\(([^)]*)\)/,a)) {
        cur=substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        end=substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        str2=str2 substr(str,1,RSTART-1) prev cur
        str=end
        prev="*write(" a[1] ");"
    }
    print str2 str prev
}
```

Given input file `input.txt`:

```
wewe sqrt(a+B)  eeenwerer ergv. sqrt(2x-3) gtgnwerer ergv. sqrt(wea*B) gjjj nwerer ergv. sqrt(a2/B) rrnwerer ergv.
```

Running `awk -f mod.awk input.txt` gives output:

```
wewe sqrt(a+B)  eeenwerer ergv. *write(a+B);sqrt(2x-3) gtgnwerer ergv. *write(2x-3);sqrt(wea*B) gjjj nwerer ergv. *write(wea*B);sqrt(a2/B) rrnwerer ergv.*write(a2/B);
```

Comment: Im getting awk: my.awk:9: fatal: 1 is invalid as number of arguments for substr Im trying read a file. could you please help me. I use the same code you gave here and name it my.awk, I want to what is the meaning of {
    str=str $0 ORS
}

Comment: `str $0 ORS` is string concatenation, for example `str="a" "b" "c"` gives `str="abc"`. `ORS` is the output record separator. It's default value is the newline character "\n"

Comment: OK Many thanks. But why am getting      awk: my.awk:9: fatal: 1 is invalid as number of arguments for substr

Comment: Can you try the code on this simple file first: `hi sqrt(a+B) you  sqrt(2x-3) gtg` ? Do you get the same error?

Comment: Ok. Try to add the following two lines after the line with `while` : `print "RSTART=\""RSTART"\""` and `print "RLENGTH=\""RLENGTH"\""`.. and then tell me what output you get for the simple file..

Comment: There is no setting of either of those variables that could produce that syntax error. I strongly suspect a copy/paste error on the part of the OP. It is worth mentioning that the 3rd arg to match() is gawk-specific but that's unrelated to that error message.

Answer (score 0):

In case the words are in a separate line you cant try this ,It will search for the word and print the line next to it.

awk '/word to search :/{getline;print;}'

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find all characters except the ')' after 'sqrt(' - you can use '[^)]*' to match this character set.
Then you can explicitly search for the patterns sqrt(...) and sqrt(...(...)....) as two separate cases.

```
sed '
    s/sqrt(\([^)]*)\)/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g
    s/sqrt(\([^)]*([^)]*)[^)]*)\)/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g
'
```

This is easier to understand if you change '[^)]*' to Z

```
sed '
    s/sqrt(\(Z)\)/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g
    s/sqrt(\(Z(Z)Z)\)/sqrt(\1) print(\1)/g
'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat similar to Håkon Hægland's solution, but shorter and works also with old versions of `awk` where `match()` cannot have 3 arguments:

```
awk -F'sqrt\\(' '
    { for (i=1; ++i<=NF; )
        $i = gensub("(.*)\\)(.*)", "sqrt(\\1)\\2 write(\\1);", 1, $i)
      print
    }           ' $LOGFILE
```